# Regular Expression and JSonPath

Tags: java, json, regex, jsonpath

I trying something with [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) v2.2.0, but I am not even sure if it is possible or not. I could not find any similar sample so I think it is better to ask before wasting too much time.

A have a JSON structure like below:

```
{
    "aspectj:aspectjrt:1.5.3:jar": {
        "groupId": "aspectj",
        "artifactId": "aspectjrt",
        "version": "1.5.3",
        "type": "jar",
        "inheritence": 1,
        "scope": "compile",
        "owningArtifacts": [
            "com.xx.yy.aa:ui:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar(T)"
        ]
    },
    "ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:0.3.11:jar": {
        "groupId": "ca.juliusdavies",
        "artifactId": "not-yet-commons-ssl",
        "version": "0.3.11",
        "type": "jar",
        "inheritence": 1,
        "scope": "compile",
        "owningArtifacts": [
            "com.xx.yy.aa:ui-war:12.47.0-SNAPSHOT:war(D)"
        ]
    },
    "cn.guoyukun.jdbc:oracle-ojdbc6:11.2.0.3.0:jar": {
        "groupId": "cn.guoyukun.jdbc",
        "artifactId": "oracle-ojdbc6",
        "version": "11.2.0.3.0",
        "type": "jar",
        "inheritence": 1,
        "scope": "compile",
        "owningArtifacts": [
            "com.xx.yy.aa:web:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar(D)"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I use a JSonPath expression like following

```
Object object = JsonPath.read(json, "$.['aspectj:aspectjrt:1.5.3:jar']");
```

I get what I want.

But I also have as requirement wildcard searches, so if the user will search
`'aspectj:aspectjrt*'` it should also get hits.

There are regular expression samples about 2nd layer elements but I could not find any about searching root element.

I have somehow created some statements but they are naturally are not working, like the following

```
Object object = JsonPath.read(json, "$[?(@=~/aspectj.*/)]");
```

Can somebody tell me what am trying to do is possible or not, if it is how should the regular expression should look?

Comment: I'm assuming you talk about Java? If not, please re-tag the question. Also, please state the exact version of the JsonPath implementation you are using.

Comment: Yep, it is Java, version is 2.2.0....

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible... maybe this is an idea for a work-around: Upon loading the JSON (after `JsonPath.parse(json)`) you could iterate the resulting object and add the keys as properties, so that `"aspectj:aspectjrt:1.5.3:jar": { ... }` would contain a key like this `"_": aspectj:aspectjrt:1.5.3:jar"`. After that you could use the regular expression against that key `"$[?(@._=~/aspectj.*/)]"`.

Comment: I had followed your idea, I have the full control over how the json will look, but I still don't get any hits from JSonPath. Now the JSon look like this '{
  "artifacts" : {
  "aspectj:aspectjrt:1.5.3:jar" : {
      "groupId" : "aspectj",
      "artifactId" : "aspectjrt",
      "version" : "1.5.3",
      "type" : "jar",
      "inheritence" : 1,
      "scope" : "compile",
      "owningArtifacts" : [
        "com.xx.yy.aa:ui:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar(T)"
      ]
    }
}' and JsonPath '$[?(@.artifacts=~/(aspectj:aspectj.*)/)]' but still don't get any hits

Comment: That's unusual. I think it's in order to post your question again, but based on your new JSON and the new search expression. This question here remains 100% valid in its own right, even though I suspect that it won't be possible to apply regex to keys (instead of to values, what the `=~` operator normally does).

Comment: Ah, I see what the error is. You still only have `'spectj:aspectjrt:1.5.3:jar'` as a *key*. You need to have it as a *value*, as well. Yes, that means duplication. In fact, instead making `artifacts` an object with keys, make it an array of objects, each having a `name` or `key` property. This pattern will turn out to be much easier to handle; the impact of no longer being able to index into the array by key will be negligible.